# Response of Modbus Protocol

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, modbus

I have the below code. This code is successfully compiling and uploading, but I am not getting any response from Slave. What do I need to do?

[image: Error message]

[image: Connection diagram]

Some time data being received from Slave (I get this error):
[image: error2]

My main code:

```
#define ID  1
/*static float ARDUINO_ANALOG_SCALING = 0.00488758;
static float Ydegree;
static int Sensor_Value;
float Yvoltage;

*/

Modbus slave(ID, 0, 0);
boolean led;
int8_t state = 0;
unsigned long tempus;
// data array for modbus network sharing
uint16_t au16data[9];
float latitude=13.08;

void setup() {
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
  slave.begin( 19200 );
  tempus = millis() + 100;
  digitalWrite(13, HIGH );
}


void loop() {

  state = slave.poll( au16data, 9 );
  if (state > 4) {
    tempus = millis() + 50;
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
  }
  if (millis() > tempus) digitalWrite(13, LOW );


  au16data[4] = analogRead(0);
  au16data[5] = analogRead(1);



  au16data[6] = slave.getInCnt();
  au16data[7] = slave.getOutCnt();
  au16data[8] = slave.getErrCnt();
}
```

Modbus code:

```
#define  MAX_BUFFER  64 
typedef struct {
  uint8_t u8id;          /*!< slave address between 1 and 247. 0 means broadcast */
  uint8_t u8fct;         /*!< function code: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 15 or 16 */
  uint16_t u16RegAdd;    /*!< address of the first register to access at slave/s */
  uint16_t u16CoilsNo;   /*!< number of coils or registers to access */
  uint16_t *au16reg;     /*!< pointer to memory image in master */
}
modbus_t;

enum {
  RESPONSE_SIZE = 6,
  EXCEPTION_SIZE = 3,
  CHECKSUM_SIZE = 2
};

enum MESSAGE {
  ID = 0,
  FUNC,
  ADD_HI,
  ADD_LO,
  NB_HI,
  NB_LO,
  BYTE_CNT
};

enum MB_FC {
  MB_FC_NONE                     = 0,   /*!< null operator */
  MB_FC_READ_COILS               = 1,   /*!< FCT=1 -> read coils or digital outputs */
  MB_FC_READ_DISCRETE_INPUT      = 2,   /*!< FCT=2 -> read digital inputs */
  MB_FC_READ_REGISTERS           = 3,   /*!< FCT=3 -> read registers or analog outputs */
  MB_FC_READ_INPUT_REGISTER      = 4,   /*!< FCT=4 -> read analog inputs */
  MB_FC_WRITE_COIL               = 5,   /*!< FCT=5 -> write single coil or output */
  MB_FC_WRITE_REGISTER           = 6,   /*!< FCT=6 -> write single register */
  MB_FC_WRITE_MULTIPLE_COILS     = 15,  /*!< FCT=15 -> write multiple coils or outputs */
  MB_FC_WRITE_MULTIPLE_REGISTERS = 16   /*!< FCT=16 -> write multiple registers */
};

enum COM_STATES {
  COM_IDLE                     = 0,
  COM_WAITING                  = 1

};

enum ERR_LIST {
  ERR_NOT_MASTER                = -1,
  ERR_POLLING                   = -2,
  ERR_BUFF_OVERFLOW             = -3,
  ERR_BAD_CRC                   = -4,
  ERR_EXCEPTION                 = -5
};


enum {
  NO_REPLY = 255,           /*!< */
  EXC_FUNC_CODE = 1,        /*!< Function code not available */
  EXC_ADDR_RANGE = 2,       /*!< Address beyond available space for Modbus registers */
  EXC_REGS_QUANT = 3,       /*!< Coils or registers number beyond the available space */
  EXC_EXECUTE = 4           /*!< */
};


const unsigned char fctsupported[] = {
  MB_FC_READ_COILS,
  MB_FC_READ_DISCRETE_INPUT,
  MB_FC_READ_REGISTERS,
  MB_FC_READ_INPUT_REGISTER,
  MB_FC_WRITE_COIL,
  MB_FC_WRITE_REGISTER,
  MB_FC_WRITE_MULTIPLE_COILS,
  MB_FC_WRITE_MULTIPLE_REGISTERS
};

#define T35  5

class Modbus {
private:
  HardwareSerial *port; //!< Pointer to Serial class object
  uint8_t u8id; //!<0=master, 1..247=slave number
  uint8_t u8serno; //!<serial port: 0-Serial, 1..3-Serial1..Serial3
  uint8_t u8txenpin; //!<flow control pin: 0=USB or RS-232 mode, >0=RS-485 mode
  uint8_t u8state;
  uint8_t au8Buffer[MAX_BUFFER];
  uint8_t u8BufferSize;
  uint8_t u8lastRec;
  uint16_t *au16regs;
  uint16_t u16InCnt, u16OutCnt, u16errCnt;
  uint16_t u16timeOut;
  uint32_t u32time, u32timeOut;
  uint8_t u8regsize;

  void init(uint8_t u8id, uint8_t u8serno, uint8_t u8txenpin);
  void sendTxBuffer(); // transmit buffer to serial port
  int8_t getRxBuffer(); // get serial buffer contents
  uint16_t calcCRC(uint8_t u8length); // get CRC from au8Buffer until u8length
  uint8_t validateAnswer();
  uint8_t validateRequest(); // validate master request
  void get_FC1(); // *** only master ***
  void get_FC3(); // *** only master ***
  int8_t process_FC1( uint16_t *regs, uint8_t u8size ); //!< *** only slave ***
  int8_t process_FC3( uint16_t *regs, uint8_t u8size ); //!< *** only slave ***
  int8_t process_FC5( uint16_t *regs, uint8_t u8size ); //!< *** only slave ***
  int8_t process_FC6( uint16_t *regs, uint8_t u8size ); //!< *** only slave ***
  int8_t process_FC15( uint16_t *regs, uint8_t u8size ); //!< *** only slave ***
  int8_t process_FC16( uint16_t *regs, uint8_t u8size ); //!< *** only slave ***
  void buildException( uint8_t u8exception ); // build exception message

public:
  Modbus(); // !< Default Constructor
  Modbus(uint8_t u8id, uint8_t u8serno); // !< Constructor
  Modbus(uint8_t u8id, uint8_t u8serno, uint8_t u8txenpin); // !< Full Constructor
  void begin(long u32speed);
  void begin();
  void setTimeOut( uint16_t u16timeout); //!< write communication watch-dog timer
  uint16_t getTimeOut(); //!< get communication watch-dog timer value
  boolean getTimeOutState(); //!< get communication watch-dog timer state
  int8_t query( modbus_t telegram ); //!< only for master
  int8_t poll(); //!< cyclic poll for master
  int8_t poll( uint16_t *regs, uint8_t u8size ); //!< cyclic poll for slave
  uint16_t getInCnt(); //!< number of incoming messages
  uint16_t getOutCnt(); //!< number of outcoming messages
  uint16_t getErrCnt(); //!< error counter
  uint8_t getID(); //!< get slave ID between 1 and 247
  uint8_t getState();
  uint8_t getLastError(); //!< get last error message
  void setID( uint8_t u8id ); //!< write new ID for the slave
  void end(); //!< finish any communication and release serial communication port
};


Modbus::Modbus() {
  init(0, 0, 0);
}


Modbus::Modbus(uint8_t u8id, uint8_t u8serno) {
  init(u8id, u8serno, 0);
}

Modbus::Modbus(uint8_t u8id, uint8_t u8serno, uint8_t u8txenpin) {
  init(u8id, u8serno, u8txenpin);
}


void Modbus::begin(long u32speed) {

  switch ( u8serno ) {
#if defined(UBRR1H)
  case 1:
    port = &Serial1;
    break;
#endif

#if defined(UBRR2H)
  case 2:
    port = &Serial2;
    break;
#endif

#if defined(UBRR3H)
  case 3:
    port = &Serial3;
    break;
#endif
  case 0:
  default:
    port = &Serial;
    break;
  }

  // port->begin(u32speed, u8config);
  port->begin(u32speed);
  if (u8txenpin > 1) { // pin 0 & pin 1 are reserved for RX/TX
    // return RS485 transceiver to transmit mode
    pinMode(u8txenpin, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(u8txenpin, LOW);
  }

  port->flush();
  u8lastRec = u8BufferSize = 0;
  u16InCnt = u16OutCnt = u16errCnt = 0;
}


void Modbus::begin() {
  begin(19200);
}

void Modbus::setID( uint8_t u8id) {
  if (( u8id != 0) && (u8id <= 247)) {
    this->u8id = u8id;
  }
}


uint8_t Modbus::getID() {
  return this->u8id;
}


void Modbus::setTimeOut( uint16_t u16timeOut) {
  this->u16timeOut = u16timeOut;
}


boolean Modbus::getTimeOutState() {
  return (millis() > u32timeOut);
}


uint16_t Modbus::getInCnt() {
  return u16InCnt;
}


uint16_t Modbus::getOutCnt() {
  return u16OutCnt;
}

uint16_t Modbus::getErrCnt() {
  return u16errCnt;
}


uint8_t Modbus::getState() {
  return u8state;
}


int8_t Modbus::query( modbus_t telegram ) {
  uint8_t u8regsno, u8bytesno;
  if (u8id != 0) return -2;
  if (u8state != COM_IDLE) return -1;

  if ((telegram.u8id == 0) || (telegram.u8id > 247)) return -3;

  au16regs = telegram.au16reg;

  // telegram header
  au8Buffer[ ID ]         = telegram.u8id;
  au8Buffer[ FUNC ]       = telegram.u8fct;
  au8Buffer[ ADD_HI ]     = highByte(telegram.u16RegAdd );
  au8Buffer[ ADD_LO ]     = lowByte( telegram.u16RegAdd );

  switch ( telegram.u8fct ) {
  case MB_FC_READ_COILS:
  case MB_FC_READ_DISCRETE_INPUT:
  case MB_FC_READ_REGISTERS:
  case MB_FC_READ_INPUT_REGISTER:
    au8Buffer[ NB_HI ]      = highByte(telegram.u16CoilsNo );
    au8Buffer[ NB_LO ]      = lowByte( telegram.u16CoilsNo );
    u8BufferSize = 6;
    break;
  case MB_FC_WRITE_COIL:
    au8Buffer[ NB_HI ]      = ((au16regs[0] > 0) ? 0xff : 0);
    au8Buffer[ NB_LO ]      = 0;
    u8BufferSize = 6;
    break;
  case MB_FC_WRITE_REGISTER:
    au8Buffer[ NB_HI ]      = highByte(au16regs[0]);
    au8Buffer[ NB_LO ]      = lowByte(au16regs[0]);
    u8BufferSize = 6;
    break;
  case MB_FC_WRITE_MULTIPLE_COILS:
    u8regsno = telegram.u16CoilsNo / 16;
    u8bytesno = u8regsno * 2;
    if ((telegram.u16CoilsNo % 16) != 0) {
      u8bytesno++;
      u8regsno++;
    }

    au8Buffer[ NB_HI ]      = highByte(telegram.u16CoilsNo );
    au8Buffer[ NB_LO ]      = lowByte( telegram.u16CoilsNo );
    au8Buffer[ NB_LO + 1 ]    = u8bytesno;
    u8BufferSize = 7;

    u8regsno = u8bytesno = 0; // now auxiliary registers
    for (uint16_t i = 0; i < telegram.u16CoilsNo; i++) {


    }
    break;

  case MB_FC_WRITE_MULTIPLE_REGISTERS:
    au8Buffer[ NB_HI ]      = highByte(telegram.u16CoilsNo );
    au8Buffer[ NB_LO ]      = lowByte( telegram.u16CoilsNo );
    au8Buffer[ NB_LO + 1 ]    = (uint8_t) ( telegram.u16CoilsNo * 2 );
    u8BufferSize = 7;

    for (uint16_t i = 0; i < telegram.u16CoilsNo; i++) {
      au8Buffer[ u8BufferSize ] = highByte( au16regs[ i ] );
      u8BufferSize++;
      au8Buffer[ u8BufferSize ] = lowByte( au16regs[ i ] );
      u8BufferSize++;
    }
    break;
  }

  sendTxBuffer();
  u8state = COM_WAITING;
  return 0;
}

int8_t Modbus::poll() {
  // check if there is any incoming frame
  uint8_t u8current = port->available();

  if (millis() > u32timeOut) {
    u8state = COM_IDLE;
    u16errCnt++;
    return 0;
  }

  if (u8current == 0) return 0;

  // check T35 after frame end or still no frame end
  if (u8current != u8lastRec) {
    u8lastRec = u8current;
    u32time = millis() + T35;
    return 0;
  }
  if (millis() < u32time) return 0;

  // transfer Serial buffer frame to auBuffer
  u8lastRec = 0;
  int8_t i8state = getRxBuffer();
  if (i8state < 7) {
    u8state = COM_IDLE;
    u16errCnt++;
    return i8state;
  }

  // validate message: id, CRC, FCT, exception
  uint8_t u8exception = validateAnswer();
  if (u8exception != 0) {
    u8state = COM_IDLE;
    return u8exception;
  }

  // process answer
  switch ( au8Buffer[ FUNC ] ) {
  case MB_FC_READ_COILS:
  case MB_FC_READ_DISCRETE_INPUT:
    // call get_FC1 to transfer the incoming message to au16regs buffer
    get_FC1( );
    break;
  case MB_FC_READ_INPUT_REGISTER:
  case MB_FC_READ_REGISTERS :
    // call get_FC3 to transfer the incoming message to au16regs buffer
    get_FC3( );
    break;
  case MB_FC_WRITE_COIL:
  case MB_FC_WRITE_REGISTER :
  case MB_FC_WRITE_MULTIPLE_COILS:
  case MB_FC_WRITE_MULTIPLE_REGISTERS :
    // nothing to do
    break;
  default:
    break;
  }
  u8state = COM_IDLE;
  return u8BufferSize;
}


int8_t Modbus::poll( uint16_t *regs, uint8_t u8size ) {

  au16regs = regs;
  u8regsize = u8size;

  // check if there is any incoming frame
  uint8_t u8current = port->available();
  if (u8current == 0) return 0;

  // check T35 after frame end or still no frame end
  if (u8current != u8lastRec) {
    u8lastRec = u8current;
    u32time = millis() + T35;
    return 0;
  }
  if (millis() < u32time) return 0;

  u8lastRec = 0;
  int8_t i8state = getRxBuffer();
  if (i8state < 7) return i8state;

  // check slave id
  if (au8Buffer[ ID ] != u8id) return 0;

  // validate message: CRC, FCT, address and size
  uint8_t u8exception = validateRequest();
  if (u8exception > 0) {
    if (u8exception != NO_REPLY) {
      buildException( u8exception );
      sendTxBuffer();
    }
    return u8exception;
  }

  u32timeOut = millis() + long(u16timeOut);

  // process message
  switch ( au8Buffer[ FUNC ] ) {
  case MB_FC_READ_COILS:
  case MB_FC_READ_DISCRETE_INPUT:
    return process_FC1( regs, u8size );
    break;
  case MB_FC_READ_INPUT_REGISTER:
  case MB_FC_READ_REGISTERS :
    return process_FC3( regs, u8size );
    break;
  case MB_FC_WRITE_COIL:
    return process_FC5( regs, u8size );
    break;
  case MB_FC_WRITE_REGISTER :
    return process_FC6( regs, u8size );
    break;
  case MB_FC_WRITE_MULTIPLE_COILS:
    return process_FC15( regs, u8size );
    break;
  case MB_FC_WRITE_MULTIPLE_REGISTERS :
    return process_FC16( regs, u8size );
    break;
  default:
    break;
  }
}

/* _____PRIVATE FUNCTIONS_____________________________________________________ */

void Modbus::init(uint8_t u8id, uint8_t u8serno, uint8_t u8txenpin) {
  this->u8id = u8id;
  this->u8serno = (u8serno > 3) ? 0 : u8serno;
  this->u8txenpin = u8txenpin;
  this->u16timeOut = 1000;
}


int8_t Modbus::getRxBuffer() {
  boolean bBuffOverflow = false;

  if (u8txenpin > 1) digitalWrite( u8txenpin, LOW );

  u8BufferSize = 0;
  while ( port->available() ) {
    au8Buffer[ u8BufferSize ] = port->read();
    u8BufferSize ++;

    if (u8BufferSize >= MAX_BUFFER) bBuffOverflow = true;
  }
  u16InCnt++;

  if (bBuffOverflow) {
    u16errCnt++;
    return ERR_BUFF_OVERFLOW;
  }
  return u8BufferSize;
}


void Modbus::sendTxBuffer() {
  uint8_t i = 0;

  // append CRC to message
  uint16_t u16crc = calcCRC( u8BufferSize );
  au8Buffer[ u8BufferSize ] = u16crc >> 8;
  u8BufferSize++;
  au8Buffer[ u8BufferSize ] = u16crc & 0x00ff;
  u8BufferSize++;

  // set RS485 transceiver to transmit mode
  if (u8txenpin > 1) {
    switch ( u8serno ) {
#if defined(UBRR1H)
    case 1:
      UCSR1A = UCSR1A | (1 << TXC1);
      break;
#endif

#if defined(UBRR2H)
    case 2:
      UCSR2A = UCSR2A | (1 << TXC2);
      break;
#endif

#if defined(UBRR3H)
    case 3:
      UCSR3A = UCSR3A | (1 << TXC3);
      break;
#endif
    case 0:
    default:
      UCSR0A = UCSR0A | (1 << TXC0);
      break;
    }
    digitalWrite( u8txenpin, HIGH );
  }

  // transfer buffer to serial line
  port->write( au8Buffer, u8BufferSize );

  // keep RS485 transceiver in transmit mode as long as sending
  if (u8txenpin > 1) {
    switch ( u8serno ) {
#if defined(UBRR1H)
    case 1:
      while (!(UCSR1A & (1 << TXC1)));
      break;
#endif

#if defined(UBRR2H)
    case 2:
      while (!(UCSR2A & (1 << TXC2)));
      break;
#endif

#if defined(UBRR3H)
    case 3:
      while (!(UCSR3A & (1 << TXC3)));
      break;
#endif
    case 0:
    default:
      while (!(UCSR0A & (1 << TXC0)));
      break;
    }

    // return RS485 transceiver to receive mode
    digitalWrite( u8txenpin, LOW );
  }
  port->flush();
  u8BufferSize = 0;

  // set time-out for master
  u32timeOut = millis() + (unsigned long) u16timeOut;

  // increase message counter
  u16OutCnt++;
}

/**
 * @brief
 * This method calculates CRC
 *
 * @return uint16_t calculated CRC value for the message
 * @ingroup buffer
 */
uint16_t Modbus::calcCRC(uint8_t u8length) {
  unsigned int temp, temp2, flag;
  temp = 0xFFFF;
  for (unsigned char i = 0; i < u8length; i++) {
    temp = temp ^ au8Buffer[i];
    for (unsigned char j = 1; j <= 8; j++) {
      flag = temp & 0x0001;
      temp >>= 1;
      if (flag)
        temp ^= 0xA001;
    }
  }
  // Reverse byte order.
  temp2 = temp >> 8;
  temp = (temp << 8) | temp2;
  temp &= 0xFFFF;
  // the returned value is already swapped
  // crcLo byte is first & crcHi byte is last
  return temp;
}

uint8_t Modbus::validateRequest() {
  // check message crc vs calculated crc
  uint16_t u16MsgCRC =
    ((au8Buffer[u8BufferSize - 2] << 8)
    | au8Buffer[u8BufferSize - 1]); // combine the crc Low & High bytes
  if ( calcCRC( u8BufferSize - 2 ) != u16MsgCRC ) {
    u16errCnt ++;
    return NO_REPLY;
  }

  // check fct code
  boolean isSupported = false;
  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < sizeof( fctsupported ); i++) {
    if (fctsupported[i] == au8Buffer[FUNC]) {
      isSupported = 1;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (!isSupported) {
    u16errCnt ++;
    return EXC_FUNC_CODE;
  }

  // check start address & nb range
  uint16_t u16regs = 0;
  uint8_t u8regs;
  switch ( au8Buffer[ FUNC ] ) {
  case MB_FC_READ_COILS:
  case MB_FC_READ_DISCRETE_INPUT:
  case MB_FC_WRITE_MULTIPLE_COILS:
    u16regs = word( au8Buffer[ ADD_HI ], au8Buffer[ ADD_LO ]) / 16;
    u16regs += word( au8Buffer[ NB_HI ], au8Buffer[ NB_LO ]) / 16;
    u8regs = (uint8_t) u16regs;
    if (u8regs > u8regsize) return EXC_ADDR_RANGE;
    break;
  case MB_FC_WRITE_COIL:
    u16regs = word( au8Buffer[ ADD_HI ], au8Buffer[ ADD_LO ]) / 16;
    u8regs = (uint8_t) u16regs;
    if (u8regs > u8regsize) return EXC_ADDR_RANGE;
    break;
  case MB_FC_WRITE_REGISTER :
    u16regs = word( au8Buffer[ ADD_HI ], au8Buffer[ ADD_LO ]);
    u8regs = (uint8_t) u16regs;
    if (u8regs > u8regsize) return EXC_ADDR_RANGE;
    break;
  case MB_FC_READ_REGISTERS :
  case MB_FC_READ_INPUT_REGISTER :
  case MB_FC_WRITE_MULTIPLE_REGISTERS :
    u16regs = word( au8Buffer[ ADD_HI ], au8Buffer[ ADD_LO ]);
    u16regs += word( au8Buffer[ NB_HI ], au8Buffer[ NB_LO ]);
    u8regs = (uint8_t) u16regs;
    if (u8regs > u8regsize) return EXC_ADDR_RANGE;
    break;
  }
  return 0; // OK, no exception code thrown
}


uint8_t Modbus::validateAnswer() {
  // check message crc vs calculated crc
  uint16_t u16MsgCRC =
    ((au8Buffer[u8BufferSize - 2] << 8)
    | au8Buffer[u8BufferSize - 1]); // combine the crc Low & High bytes
  if ( calcCRC( u8BufferSize - 2 ) != u16MsgCRC ) {
    u16errCnt ++;
    return NO_REPLY;
  }

  // check exception
  if ((au8Buffer[ FUNC ] & 0x80) != 0) {
    u16errCnt ++;
    return ERR_EXCEPTION;
  }

  // check fct code
  boolean isSupported = false;
  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < sizeof( fctsupported ); i++) {
    if (fctsupported[i] == au8Buffer[FUNC]) {
      isSupported = 1;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (!isSupported) {
    u16errCnt ++;
    return EXC_FUNC_CODE;
  }

  return 0; // OK, no exception code thrown
}


void Modbus::buildException( uint8_t u8exception ) {
  uint8_t u8func = au8Buffer[ FUNC ];  // get the original FUNC code

  au8Buffer[ ID ]      = u8id;
  au8Buffer[ FUNC ]    = u8func + 0x80;
  au8Buffer[ 2 ]       = u8exception;
  u8BufferSize         = EXCEPTION_SIZE;
}


void Modbus::get_FC1() {
  uint8_t u8byte, i;
  u8byte = 0;

  // check the answer length
  boolean bEvenOdd =
    ( au8Buffer[ ADD_HI ] % 2 == 0) ?
  false :
  true;

  uint8_t u8WordsNo =
    ( !bEvenOdd ) ?
  au8Buffer[ ADD_HI ] / 2 :
  au8Buffer[ ADD_HI ] / 2 + 1;

  for (i = 0; i < u8WordsNo; i++) {
    au16regs[ i ] = word(
    au8Buffer[ u8byte ],
    au8Buffer[ u8byte + 1 ]);
    u8byte += 2;
  }

  // cut last byte
  if (bEvenOdd) {
    au16regs[ u8WordsNo - 1 ] &= 0xff00;
  }
}

void Modbus::get_FC3() {
  uint8_t u8byte, i;
  u8byte = 3;

  for (i = 0; i < au8Buffer[ 2 ] / 2; i++) {
    au16regs[ i ] = word(
    au8Buffer[ u8byte ],
    au8Buffer[ u8byte + 1 ]);
    u8byte += 2;
  }
}


int8_t Modbus::process_FC1( uint16_t *regs, uint8_t u8size ) {
  uint8_t u8currentRegister, u8currentBit, u8bytesno, u8bitsno;
  uint8_t u8CopyBufferSize;
  uint16_t u16currentCoil, u16coil;

  // get the first and last coil from the message
  uint16_t u16StartCoil = word( au8Buffer[ ADD_HI ], au8Buffer[ ADD_LO ] );
  uint16_t u16Coilno = word( au8Buffer[ NB_HI ], au8Buffer[ NB_LO ] );

  // put the number of bytes in the outcoming message
  u8bytesno = (uint8_t) (u16Coilno / 8);
  if (u16Coilno % 8 != 0) u8bytesno ++;
  au8Buffer[ ADD_HI ]  = u8bytesno;
  u8BufferSize         = ADD_LO;

  // read each coil from the register map and put its value inside the outcoming message
  u8bitsno = 0;

  for (u16currentCoil = 0; u16currentCoil < u16Coilno; u16currentCoil++) {
    u16coil = u16StartCoil + u16currentCoil;
    u8currentRegister = (uint8_t) (u16coil / 16);
    u8currentBit = (uint8_t) (u16coil % 16);

    bitWrite(
    au8Buffer[ u8BufferSize ],
    u8bitsno,
    bitRead( regs[ u8currentRegister ], u8currentBit ) );
    u8bitsno ++;

    if (u8bitsno > 7) {
      u8bitsno = 0;
      u8BufferSize++;
    }
  }

  // send outcoming message
  if (u16Coilno % 8 != 0) u8BufferSize ++;
  u8CopyBufferSize = u8BufferSize +2;
  sendTxBuffer();
  return u8CopyBufferSize;
}

int8_t Modbus::process_FC3( uint16_t *regs, uint8_t u8size ) {

  uint8_t u8StartAdd = word( au8Buffer[ ADD_HI ], au8Buffer[ ADD_LO ] );
  uint8_t u8regsno = word( au8Buffer[ NB_HI ], au8Buffer[ NB_LO ] );
  uint8_t u8CopyBufferSize;
  uint8_t i;

  au8Buffer[ 2 ]       = u8regsno * 2;
  u8BufferSize         = 3;

  for (i = u8StartAdd; i < u8StartAdd + u8regsno; i++) {
    au8Buffer[ u8BufferSize ] = highByte(regs[i]);
    u8BufferSize++;
    au8Buffer[ u8BufferSize ] = lowByte(regs[i]);
    u8BufferSize++;
  }
  u8CopyBufferSize = u8BufferSize +2;
  sendTxBuffer();

  return u8CopyBufferSize;
}


int8_t Modbus::process_FC5( uint16_t *regs, uint8_t u8size ) {
  uint8_t u8currentRegister, u8currentBit;
  uint8_t u8CopyBufferSize;
  uint16_t u16coil = word( au8Buffer[ ADD_HI ], au8Buffer[ ADD_LO ] );

  // point to the register and its bit
  u8currentRegister = (uint8_t) (u16coil / 16);
  u8currentBit = (uint8_t) (u16coil % 16);

  // write to coil
  bitWrite(
  regs[ u8currentRegister ],
  u8currentBit,
  au8Buffer[ NB_HI ] == 0xff );


  // send answer to master
  u8BufferSize = 6;
  u8CopyBufferSize = u8BufferSize +2;
  sendTxBuffer();

  return u8CopyBufferSize;

}


int8_t Modbus::process_FC6( uint16_t *regs, uint8_t u8size ) {

  uint8_t u8add = word( au8Buffer[ ADD_HI ], au8Buffer[ ADD_LO ] );
  uint8_t u8CopyBufferSize;
  uint16_t u16val = word( au8Buffer[ NB_HI ], au8Buffer[ NB_LO ] );

  regs[ u8add ] = u16val;

  // keep the same header
  u8BufferSize         = RESPONSE_SIZE;

  u8CopyBufferSize = u8BufferSize +2;
  sendTxBuffer();

  return u8CopyBufferSize;
}


int8_t Modbus::process_FC15( uint16_t *regs, uint8_t u8size ) {
  uint8_t u8currentRegister, u8currentBit, u8frameByte, u8bitsno;
  uint8_t u8CopyBufferSize;
  uint16_t u16currentCoil, u16coil;
  boolean bTemp;

  // get the first and last coil from the message
  uint16_t u16StartCoil = word( au8Buffer[ ADD_HI ], au8Buffer[ ADD_LO ] );
  uint16_t u16Coilno = word( au8Buffer[ NB_HI ], au8Buffer[ NB_LO ] );


  // read each coil from the register map and put its value inside the outcoming message
  u8bitsno = 0;
  u8frameByte = 7;
  for (u16currentCoil = 0; u16currentCoil < u16Coilno; u16currentCoil++) {

    u16coil = u16StartCoil + u16currentCoil;
    u8currentRegister = (uint8_t) (u16coil / 16);
    u8currentBit = (uint8_t) (u16coil % 16);

    bTemp = bitRead(
    au8Buffer[ u8frameByte ],
    u8bitsno );

    bitWrite(
    regs[ u8currentRegister ],
    u8currentBit,
    bTemp );

    u8bitsno ++;

    if (u8bitsno > 7) {
      u8bitsno = 0;
      u8frameByte++;
    }
  }

  // send outcoming message
  // it's just a copy of the incomping frame until 6th byte
  u8BufferSize         = 6;
  u8CopyBufferSize = u8BufferSize +2;
  sendTxBuffer();
  return u8CopyBufferSize;
}


int8_t Modbus::process_FC16( uint16_t *regs, uint8_t u8size ) {
  uint8_t u8func = au8Buffer[ FUNC ];  // get the original FUNC code
  uint8_t u8StartAdd = au8Buffer[ ADD_HI ] << 8 | au8Buffer[ ADD_LO ];
  uint8_t u8regsno = au8Buffer[ NB_HI ] << 8 | au8Buffer[ NB_LO ];
  uint8_t u8CopyBufferSize;
  uint8_t i;
  uint16_t temp;

  // build header
  au8Buffer[ NB_HI ]   = 0;
  au8Buffer[ NB_LO ]   = u8regsno;
  u8BufferSize         = RESPONSE_SIZE;

  // write registers
  for (i = 0; i < u8regsno; i++) {
    temp = word(
    au8Buffer[ (BYTE_CNT + 1) + i * 2 ],
    au8Buffer[ (BYTE_CNT + 2) + i * 2 ]);

    regs[ u8StartAdd + i ] = temp;
  }
  u8CopyBufferSize = u8BufferSize +2;
  sendTxBuffer();

  return u8CopyBufferSize;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My testing indicates that the slave **is** responding. I made up a master from http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/ModbusMaster and tested it:

[image: Modbus response]

- Channel 0 is master to slave.
- Channel 1 is slave to master.

Zooming in:

[image: Modbus response 2]

Comment: I would like to know how you have analyzed this. Is it from an emulation, an oscilloscope or some PC-oscilloscope-software thing?